# How to get Clicked Nodes text of RadTreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, radtreeview

How do I get the text of clicked nodes in RadTreeView in C#? I added the OnNodeClick event but it is not firing. Please tell me how to get text of the clicked node in C#.

ASP.NET:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="CandidatesTreeMenu" OnClientNodeClicked="ClientCandidateMenuNodeClicked" Skin="Vista" runat="server" OnNodeClick="CandidatesTreeMenu_NodeClick">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Added" NavigateUrl="NewCandidateList.aspx?type=recently">
        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Candidates" NavigateUrl="NewCandidateList.aspx?type=My">
        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void CandidatesTreeMenu_NodeClick(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string CheckNodeName = e.Node.Text;

    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rebind at every post back in the user control page_load event.
Here the code I used in the ascx:

```
<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CandidatesTreeMenu.NodeClick += CandidatesTreeMenu_NodeClick;
    }
    protected void CandidatesTreeMenu_NodeClick(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        string CheckNodeName = e.Node.Text;
    }

</script>
<telerik:RadScriptBlock runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ClientCandidateMenuNodeClicked(sender, args) {
            // noop
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="CandidatesTreeMenu" OnClientNodeClicked="ClientCandidateMenuNodeClicked" Skin="Vista" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Added" NavigateUrl="NewCandidateList.aspx?type=recently">
        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Candidates" NavigateUrl="NewCandidateList.aspx?type=My">
        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```